# Can i redirect the google analytics snippet to my Server?

Tags: javascript, php, google-analytics, tracking

I need to implement web analytics on my website http://www.example.com. I found that the Google's analytics snippet can be added to the 'footer.php' of my website, and this will trigger Google's [ga function](https://www.google-analytics.com/ga.js) thereby provide analytics dashboards and so on.

I have to know whether I can alter the JavaScript snippet to redirect data to my server, as to get the raw data and process them.

Edit: I have found this code below, by googling. But I was not able to understand what it actually does, being too much beginner to JavaScript.

```
<script>
(function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
(i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
 m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
})(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

ga('create', 'UA-XXXXX-YY', 'auto');

// START remote backup of GA data request for Angelfish
ga(function(tracker) {
  var originalSendHitTask = tracker.get('sendHitTask');
  tracker.set('sendHitTask', function(model) {
   var payLoad = model.get('hitPayload');
   originalSendHitTask(model);
   var gifRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
   // Send __ua.gif to a remote server
   var gifPath = "https://www.your-domain.com/__ua.gif";
   gifRequest.open('GET', gifPath + '?' + payLoad, false);
   gifRequest.send();
  });
});
// END remote backup of GA data request for Angelfish

ga('send', 'pageview');
</script>
```

Comment: This does the same as the code in my answer below, only it uses a GET request rather than POST.  What it does is explained in the documentation I linked to - it calls an image and appends the "payload", i.e. the parameters Google uses for tracking. The request with the parameters will appear in your server log files (or you make this a script that writes the data to a file before it sends an images), and from there you can extract and parse the data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can redirect the data by adding to the sendHitTask, which is actually explained [by example in the GA documentation](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/tasks#adding_to_a_task):

```
ga('create', 'UA-XXXXX-Y', 'auto');

ga(function(tracker) {

  // Grab a reference to the default sendHitTask function.
  var originalSendHitTask = tracker.get('sendHitTask');

  // Modifies sendHitTask to send a copy of the request to a local server after
  // sending the normal request to www.google-analytics.com/collect.
  tracker.set('sendHitTask', function(model) {
    originalSendHitTask(model);
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('POST', '/localhits', true);
    xhr.send(model.get('hitPayload'));
  });
});

ga('send', 'pageview');
```

The second part of the question (how to process) is to broad to answer here.

Comment: I keep meaning to try that.  Wondering exactly how much data there is.

Comment: @Eike Pierstorff Thank you. Where do I enter the path to my server?

Comment: That's the line xhr.open('POST', '/localhits', true). Your replace /localhits with the path to your server.  You need a script that writes the post parameters to a log file that you can later parse into fields for aggregation.

Comment: @DaImTo, depends on your site of course, but not unreasonably much (especially in the era of cloud services where you can dump the data to a Amazon EC2 instance). The problem is rather to find something interesting to do with the data that is not already done by GA itself or related tools.

Comment: To throw in a plug to my own stuff, I wrote a GA plugin to do double tracking which also accepts a custom path for the secondary tracker: http://www.flesheatingarthropods.org/double-tracking-in-ga-part-1/ (or at github: https://github.com/flesheatingarthropods/universal-analytics-dual-tracking-plugin). I'm not sure one should use this in production, but it might give you some ideas.

Comment: I tried it and provided an S3 bucket address (eg: s3://mybucket/mydata/) to dump the data. Even after an hour, nothing showed up.

Comment: Which one did you try, the Google Example or the plugin (if it's the later I'll check later this day, this used to work when I tested it).

Comment: the code for adding to the sendHitTask in your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Finally found the answer, Thanks to @Eike Pierstorff.

First I appended the following script before the `</body>` tag of websites footer.php

```
<script>
(function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
(i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
})(window,document,'script','https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

 ga('create', 'UA-XXXXX-Y', 'auto');

 ga(function(tracker) {

  // Grab a reference to the default sendHitTask function.
  var originalSendHitTask = tracker.get('sendHitTask');

  // Modifies sendHitTask to send a copy of the request to a local server after
  // sending the normal request to www.google-analytics.com/collect.
  tracker.set('sendHitTask', function(model) {
  originalSendHitTask(model);
  var payLoad = model.get('hitPayload');
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  var gifPath = 'http://YourPath/process_ga_data.php';

  xhr.open('GET', gifPath + '?' + payLoad, false);
  xhr.send();

  });
});

ga('send', 'pageview');
</script>
```

And in the server to which I am pushing the Google analytics payload, the following PHP code was written, as to fetch all the parameters into Output.txt as an array.

```
 if (isset($_REQUEST))
 $req_dump = print_r($_REQUEST, TRUE);  
 $file = file_put_contents('output.txt', $req_dump.PHP_EOL, FILE_APPEND);  
 fclose($file);
```

But still, not all the [Measurement Protocol](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/parameters#ecomm) parameters are listing, I have to further configure that.

P.S. I will edit this answer, once I find out a way to fetch all the parameters.